# Can´t get node express server to run

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, cors

I want to setup a node server with express to run nodmailer. My frontend is builded with cra - I think there are no problems in that zone.
My questions are:
Why does my express server doesnt work right?
Why do I get an error telling me 'XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/send_mail due to access control checks.'?
Where is the fu&%!§g error in this script?

The folder structure does looks like that:

1. backend (folder)

- .env
- index.js

2. frontend (folder)

- public (subfolder)
- src (subfolder)
- index.js
- App.js
- Mailer.js

There is one package.json in the frontend and one in the backend folder.
In the express application *app.listen* works in console, but console.log of *app.get* doesnt work and browser just shows that it cant connect to localhost:5000.

Here is my backend/**index.js**:

```
const express = require('express');
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
const cors = require('cors');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

const app = express();
require('dotenv').config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

app.use(cors());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  console.log(`this text should be visible in browser`);
  res.send('API is running...');
});

app.post('/send_mail', cors(), async (req, res) => {
  let { text } = req.body;
  const transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: process.env.MAIL_HOST,
    port: process.env.MAIL_PORT,
    auth: {
      user: process.env.MAIL_USER,
      pass: process.env.MAIL_PASS,
    },
  });

  await transport.sendMail({
    from: `${email}`,
    to: 'test@test.com',
    html: `<div className="email">
        <h2>Here is your email!</h2>
        <p>${text}</p>
         </div>
    `,
  });
});

app.listen(
  (PORT,
  () => {
    console.log(`Server is listening on port ${PORT}`);
  })
);
```

and here is my **package.json** from backend folder:

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "react contact form backend server",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "nodemon ./index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Itsme",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemailer": "^6.6.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12"
  }
}
```

Additional the frontend part:
**Mailer.js:**

```
import axios from 'axios';
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Mailer = () => {
  const [sent, setSent] = useState(false);
  const [text, setText] = useState('');

  const handleSend = async (e) => {
    setSent(true);
    try {
      await axios.post('http://localhost:5000/send_mail', {
        text,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className='Mailer'>
      {!sent ? (
        <form onSubmit={handleSend}>
          <input
            type='text'
            value={text}
            onChange={(e) => setText(e.target.value)}
          />
          <button type='submit'>Send</button>
        </form>
      ) : (
        <h3>Thanks for your message</h3>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Mailer;
```

**App.js:**

```
import './App.css';
import Mailer from './Mailer';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <Mailer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: well, I assume your front end is not running on port 5000, right? So then localhost:5000 would be a different origin and this would be a 100% normal and correct error exactly as that error indicates. Have you already looked it up?

Comment: First, you don't need to use that kind of language. Second, how do you start the backend server ? And also provide the env files.

Comment: Seems a CORS issue, check your `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` HTTP header. Also are you using the app served by express or your local file directly? because this could lead to this kind of problem.

Comment: @ChristianFritz I'm not sure if I heard of using back- and frontend on the same port before.

Comment: @asdru Thanks, but that's exactly what cors should manage

Comment: I mean, if you open the app from a different domain (or just from another port), when you make the request to localhost:5000, it will die because of CORS, If you want to be able to make calls to localhost:5000, then you have to fix the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header or be sure that the app is served from the same origin (protocol, host and port).

Answer (score -1):

CORS is blocking u from sending an POST request, U need to add this code to your index.js:

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    next();
  });
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work - same issue @damjance